# System cannot be solved with methods available

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

```
eqn = (-(Sqrt[3 - P] - I*Sqrt[P]) + (Sqrt[3 - P] + I*Sqrt[P])*
  Exp[-2*Pi*Sqrt[3 - P]])/((Sqrt[3 - P] - 
   I*Sqrt[P]) + (Sqrt[3 - P] + I*Sqrt[P])*
  Exp[-2*Pi*Sqrt[3 - P]]) == I*Sqrt[P/(3 - P)]*(1 + Exp[-2*I*Pi*Sqrt[P]])/(1 - 
  Exp[-2*I*Pi*Sqrt[P]]);

eqn //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{e^{-2 \pi  \sqrt{3-P}} \left(\sqrt{3-P}+i \sqrt{P}\right)-\sqrt{3-P}+i
>    \sqrt{P}}{e^{-2 \pi  \sqrt{3-P}} \left(\sqrt{3-P}+i \sqrt{P}\right)+\sqrt{3-P}-i
>    \sqrt{P}}=\frac{i \left(1+e^{-2 i \pi  \sqrt{P}}\right) \sqrt{\frac{P}{3-P}}}{1-e^{-2
>    i \pi  \sqrt{P}}}$

The command [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) hasn't been successful so far:

```
Solve[eqn, P]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a transcendental equation.I doubt whether it will find exliptic solution.

Comment: You can try plotting the equation and find an approximate solution with `FindRoot`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: It helps to start by visualising your function (difference between the left and right sides of your equation) by creating contour plots in the complex `P` plane, so you can see where the function's zeros are likely to be. For instance, you could start with `ContourPlot[Abs[func[x + I y]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -2, 2}]` (`Arg` is done analogously).

Answer (score 5):

`Solve`, `Reduce`, `NSolve`  can not solve this problem; this is a transcendental equation. It can only be solved numerically.

$$\left\{\frac{e^{-2 \pi  \sqrt{3-P}} \left(\sqrt{3-P}+i
   \sqrt{P}\right)-\sqrt{3-P}+i \sqrt{P}}{e^{-2 \pi  \sqrt{3-P}}
   \left(\sqrt{3-P}+i \sqrt{P}\right)+\sqrt{3-P}-i \sqrt{P}}-\frac{i
   \left(1+e^{-2 i \pi  \sqrt{P}}\right) \sqrt{\frac{P}{3-P}}}{1-e^{-2 i \pi 
   \sqrt{P}}}=0\right\}$$

```
 eq = {(-(Sqrt[3 - P] - I*Sqrt[P]) + (Sqrt[3 - P] + I*Sqrt[P])*
    Exp[-2*Pi*Sqrt[3 - P]])/((Sqrt[3 - P] - 
     I*Sqrt[P]) + (Sqrt[3 - P] + I*Sqrt[P])*
    Exp[-2*Pi*Sqrt[3 - P]]) - 
 I Sqrt[P/(3 - P)] (1 + Exp[-2*I Pi Sqrt[P]])/(1 - 
    Exp[-2*I Pi Sqrt[P]]) == 0}
```

In the real domain:

```
  Plot[Evaluate[Re@eq[[1, 1]]], {P, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
{FindRoot[Re@eq[[1, 1]], {P, 0.5}], FindRoot[Re@eq[[1, 1]], {P, 2.5}]}
```

> ```
> {{P -> 0.703961}, {P -> 2.62104}}
> ```

In the complex domain:

```
 Plot[Evaluate[Im@eq[[1, 1]]], {P, 5, 30}]
```

[image]

> ```
> {{P -> 6.54838}, {P -> 12.1886}, {P -> 20.0831}}
> ```

As you can see from this plot, the equation has a infinitely many solutions in the complex domain.

[image]

Comment: @belisarius.Expand your question?

Comment: If you evaluate `Plot[Evaluate[Abs[Subtract @@@ eq]], {P, 0, 100}]` The zeroes should be there ...

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a domain restriction for [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) to find any solutions:

```
zeros = P /. Solve[eq && -5 < Re[P] < 5 && -5 < Im[P] < 5, P];
```

> Solve::fexp: Warning: Solve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.
>
> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.

The result `zeros` is a complicated looking set of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects which can be numericized to any desired precision. At machine precision we have:

```
N[zeros]
```

> {0.703961 - 0.0000232491 I, 2.62093 - 0.00664407 I, 3.95346 - 0.275317 I}

Let's check numerically if `zeros` satisfies the equation:

```
eq /. P -> N[zeros, 100]
```

> True